# how to get num_rows in my views

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have code which has take values form db and have to take number of rows

Code:

```
<?php
//$no=$query2->num_rows();
foreach($query2 as $row)
{
//$no=0;
$i=1;
if($i!=$no)
{
?>   
<li><a href="jobs/view_jobs.php?id=<?php echo $row->id;?>"><?php echo $row->title;?>(
<?php
$jcid=$row->id;
echo $no;
?>
)</a></li>
<?php
    }
    else
    {
?>
<li class="last"><a href="jobs/view_jobs.php?job_id=<?php echo $row->id;?>"><?php echo $row->title;?> (
<?php
echo $no;
?>
)</a></li>
<?php
    }
$i++;
}
```

?>

what should i do for getting num_rows into my views..

Thanks in advance,
amith

Comment: $num_rows = $query2->num_rows();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the `count` of the array you have passed to the view to get the num rows.

```
$num_rows = count($query2);
```

Or return the num_rows from the model and load it to the view.

```
$returnArray    = array();
$returnArray['num_rows']    = $query2->num_rows();  //get num_rows before you do the result()
$returnArray['result']      = $query2->result();
return $returnArray;
```

Now, in the controller :

```
$data['query2'] = $this->re_model->cat_getall();
$this->load->view('view_name', $data);
```

Now in the view to get the num_rows:

```
$query2['num_rows']
```

To get the result and to loop the result:

```
foreach($query2['result'] as $row)
```

Comment: how should i load it to the view

Comment: return the `num_rows()` from the model to the controller and load it to view just like you load `$query2`

Comment: i have returned in my model like  return $query2->num_rows(); and in controller  $data['query2'] = $this->re_model->cat_getall(); and this should be taken to my view.

Comment: thanks i got it how to load to my view thanks for your information

Answer (score 0):

use CIs `num_rows()`  before returning it as result_array() or result()..

```
 $query2->num_rows();  //get num_rows before you do the result()
 $query2->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this-

```
$this->db->get('table_name')-> num_rows();
```

you should see [This](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html) link.

Comment: i want the no of rows to be displayed  like in             $sql="SELECT * FROM `job_category`";         $res=mysql_query($sql);      $no=mysql_num_rows($res);

Comment: if you want that number of rows are display on view then take the above query result in a globle variable and then echo this variable at anywhere you want to display it.